# What is the efficient way to load and cache multiple Bitmaps?

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap, stability

In the "drawable" folder I have four background images of 1024 x 768 or something.

However, it turns out to be that I have to use **Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()** and my Android device is 2560 x 1504. Which means a Bitmap with the size of 2560 x 1504 is required to fill the whole screen with a background, it is really memory-consuming because it is a Bitmap of impressive size.

For some reason, I need to cache 4 bitmaps like this so my program can instantly switch to a new background when I press a button. Which means I am facing huge memory problems now. Is there any way to optimize it?

P.S: I am using ImageView class to display images. 
The images files in the "drawable" folder are not BMP files.

Comment: save those images in external memory not in cache memory

Comment: Good idea. I want to know how to do that.

Comment: i think glide might be useful read this article https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d

Comment: I do not think I need external libraries right now. I am learning the basics.

Comment: I solved my question for now, by loading each image the moment you need them. Loading all images at once on startup will cause a very high memory consumption and may result in a memory exception.

Comment: You can use Glide , instead of writing your own code which may cause many issues and bugs , You can use well established and efficient library like glide , Its very easy to use ..

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it and see.